# Javamail sign message with inline images

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sign

Signing and sending messages via Javamail library is straightforward. The same goes if you want to include images inside HTML body. What about sending an email signed that includes images? The result I am getting is the images attached, which is something I do not want to. Is there any way to do this without using spring libraries, just plain java.

Thank you in advance